# How to fix an odd @media conflict?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[@media conflict?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lzyQ.jpg)

I'm running two media queries in order to change the padding and alignment of a div (.contact-info) based upon screen size:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1501px) and (max-width: 5000px) {
  .contact-info {
      padding-top: 198px !important;
      text-align: left !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .contact-info {
      padding-top: 0px !important;
      text-align: center !important;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if the first @media won't even activate when associated with the .contact-info div. Only the second one appears to be associated with the .contact-info div, so the whole thing is ending up disjointed.

I've attached an image for reference.

Comment: You can get rid of the `and (max-width: 5000px)` in your first @media and of the `and (min-width: 0px)` in the second. Try to clear browser cache as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Unfortunately no matter what I do with caching in any browser (clearing the cache, disabling the cache, etc.), there's still faulty behavior related to the media queries. I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine!
While it is a useful practice to be careful with your specificity as the answer above showed, it is not what is causing this issue here because you specified the media queries and they are different.
Your code works fine. I tried it here: https://codepen.io/kdgyimah/details/GRZRpMm
`[https://codepen.io/kdgyimah/details/GRZRpMm][1]`

I made the background colors change when you hit the breakpoints you specified and it works

**Are you sure you have disabled cache in your browser?** The page might be loading a saved cache/version of an older css version before this code was added.
*Depending on the browser you are using the solution might be different but in Chrome:*

1. Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then select
   “More tools” > “Developer tools“. You can also get to this screen by
   pressing Ctrl + Shift + I for Windows and Linux or Command + Option + I for Mac OS X.
2. The Dev Tools window appears.
3. Select “Network“, Check the “Disable cache” box.

If you are using firefox use this one to **disable cache**: https://dzone.com/articles/how-turn-firefox-browser-cache

And reload the page. This should load up the most recent or saved version of your CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Unfortunately no matter what I do with caching in any browser (clearing the cache, disabling the cache, etc.), there's still faulty behavior related to the media queries. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: @cthebiz From what you narrated I don't think it has anything to do with the cache, possibly it is from the WordPress theme you are using, which is overriding the styles you added dynamically.

Try doing an **inspect element** on the div you want to style and see what is responsible for styling it and click the **+** icon (New style rule) after selecting the element to get a more specific selector to that div element.

Then use that instead to add the media queries.